# Head of a Reich takes a seat

Tags: riddle, knowledge, history

> A fabric is used for a pretty silk dress,
>   an empire eventually broke under stress,
>   a language once used one's ideas to express,
>   a man, head of Reich long before the SS.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fabric is used for a pretty silk dress,

> [Ottoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman_(textile)) is a silk fabric used for formal dresses.

an empire eventually broke under stress,

> The Ottoman empire, from 1299 to 1923, broken by the Allied Powers in the aftermath of WWI.

a language once used one's ideas to express,

> The [Ottoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman_Turkish_language) language, a variety of Turkish.

a man, head of Reich long before the SS.

> Otto the man, one of whom was Otto I the Great, the first Holy Roman Emperor.

Title: Head of a Reich takes a seat

> An ottoman is a piece of furniture in the form of a couch or stool.

Comment: Spot on once again. I think you may very well be irriddlable.

Comment: Where’s the green tick?

Comment: @CasablancaKookie Look, there it is! :p

Comment: I’m spending the whole time here

Comment: @jafe - that's the prefix, you're the suffix, I'm the infix.